# Get difference values between rows in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I have a result set from psycopg2 like so

```
(
(timestamp1, val11, val12, val13, val14),
(timestamp2, val21, val22, val23, val24),
(timestamp3, val31, val32, val33, val34),
(timestamp4, val41, val42, val43, val44),
)
```

I have to return the difference between the values of the row (exception for the timestamp column).
Each row would subtract the previous row values.
The first row would be

`timestamp, 'NaN', 'NaN' ....`

This has to then be returned as a generic object
Ie something like an array of the following objects

```
Group(timestamp=timestamp, rows=[val11, val12, val13, val14]
```

I was going to use Pandas to do the diff.
Something like below works ok on the values

```
df = DataFrame().from_records(data=results, columns=headers)
diffs = df.set_index('time', drop=False).diff()
```

But diff also performs on the timestamp column and I can't get it to ignore a column while
leaving the original timestamp column in place.

Also I wasn't sure it was going to be efficient to get the data into my return format
as Pandas advises against row access

What would a fast way to get the result set differences in my required output format ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why did you set `drop=False`? That puts the timestamps in the index (where they will not be touched by `diff`) but also leaves a copy of the timestamps as a proper column, to be process by `diff`.

I think this will do what you want:

```
diffs = df.set_index('time').diff().reset_index()
```

Since you mention psycopg2, take a look at the docs for pandas 0.14, released just a few days ago, which features improved SQL functionality, including new support for postgresql. You can read and write directly between the database and pandas DataFrames.

Comment: Answer is correct but in the end I just used numpy directly. As pandas converting to Series for each row then returning NaT for rows of all NaN was causing too many issues.